# Does EF Core 3.0 do not support .net framework any more?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have used EF CORE 2.2.6 in a .net framework 4.8 WPF project yet.

And now the EF CORE 3.0 has published.

While I update the NuGet package, it reports this error:

[image]

As the error said, it seems the EF CORE 3.0 does not compatible with the .net framework yet.

I tried to find the EF CORE 3.0 publish announcement, but can not find any about does not support .net framework anymore.

How can I solve it? Do I have to migrate all the project to .net core 3.0 to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EF Core 3.0** is based on **.NET Standard 2.1** while **.NET Framework 4.8** does not have **.NET Standard 2.1 support**. So you can not use EF Core 3.0 in .NET Framework 4.8.

So solution is either stick to EF Core 2.2 or migrate all the project to .NET Core 3.0.

For more details: [Support .Net Framework (4.8?) for netstandard 2.1](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/859) and [EF Core 3.0 targets .NET Standard 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#ef-core-30-targets-net-standard-21-rather-than-net-standard-20)

Answer (score 2):

FYI: EF Core 3.1 now targets .NET Standard 2.0 again. This brings back support for .NET Framework.

Comment: what is FYI ? you should explain how your answer resolves the concern of OP